# Send In App Message to Android by C# .NET using Firebase In App Messaging

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I just want to ask is there any possibility right now to Send Firebase In App Message without using Firebase Console? I want to send In App Message (FIAM) to Android App from .NET C# MVC Web Application. I managed to send Push Notification(FCM) succesfully but what about In App Messaging? Is there any API available for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is no API to configure the messages delivered/displayed by [Firebase In-app Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging). If this is a use-case you'd like to see added, I recommend you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

The closest work-around at the moment would be to use Firebase Remote Config (which does have an [API for setting configuration data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest)) to deliver some value to your clients, and then have your clients display the message on those conditions. This is somewhat similar to what Firebase's In-app Messaging does behind the scenes, although (as far as I know) it uses its own infrastructure to deliver the configuration data.

Comment: Thanks mate...really appreciate it...I think thats the only best work-around right now.